# how to reference an html image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a web page that is going to display a number of images on an HTML5 canvas.

I am loading the images in a hidden section in the HTML first, before using JavaScript to draw them on the canvas, in order to speed up the amount of time is takes them to load and be rendered on the canvas.

Once all of the images have been drawn to the canvas, it must be possible to drag and drop them around the canvas. The purpose being that there will be four 'description buckets' also displayed on the canvas, and the user is required to drag each image to its corresponding description bucket.

Once I have loaded the images in the HTML, I want to create a JavaScript array to store them in while they're being accessed and manipulated by the JavaScript, i.e. I want to be able to manipulate them as if they are JavaScript images, although their sources will be HTML elements, not the direct source of the image.

I'm following the tutorial at: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/ which does exactly what I want to do, except that the images are static. With my game, I will be providing a web form which the administrator will be able to use to change the images that are displayed depending on in what context they are using the game.

This is why where that tutorial has the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var sources = {
      beach: "beach.png",
      snake: "snake.png",
      snake_glow: "snake-glow.png",
      snake_black: "snake-black.png",
      lion: "lion.png",
      lion_glow: "lion-glow.png",
      lion_black: "lion-black.png",
      monkey: "monkey.png",
      monkey_glow: "monkey-glow.png",
      monkey_black: "monkey-black.png",
      giraffe: "giraffe.png",
      giraffe_glow: "giraffe-glow.png",
      giraffe_black: "giraffe-black.png",
    };
    loadImages(sources, initStage);
  };
```

I want to change the sources to be those of the images that I have loaded in the hidden section of the HTML:

```
<section hidden>
<img id="startButton" src="images/startButton.png" alt="Start Button" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();"/>

<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" />
<img id="chair" src="images/assets/chair.gif" alt="Asset" />
<img id="drink" src="images/assets/drink.gif" alt="Asset" />
<img id="food" src = "images/assets/food.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="fridge" src = "images/assets/fridge.png" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="land" src = "images/assets/land.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="money" src = "images/assets/money.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="oven" src = "images/assets/oven.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="table" src = "images/assets/table.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="van" src = "images/assets/van.jpg" alt="Asset"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/expenses/direct/burger.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/expenses/direct/chips.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/expenses/direct/drink.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="franchiseFee" src = "images/expenses/direct/franchiseFee.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="wages" src = "images/expenses/direct/wages.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>

<img id="admin" src = "images/expenses/indirect/admin.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="cleaners" src = "images/expenses/indirect/cleaners.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/expenses/indirect/electricity.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="insurance" src = "images/expenses/indirect/insurance.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="manager" src = "images/expenses/indirect/manager.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="rates" src = "images/expenses/indirect/rates.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="training" src = "images/expenses/indirect/training.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="water" src = "images/expenses/indirect/water.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/income/burger.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/income/chips.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/income/drink.jpg" alt="Income"/>

<img id="creditors" src = "images/liabilities/creditors.gif" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/liabilities/electricity.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="food" src = "images/liabilities/food.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="hirePurchase" src = "images/liabilities/hirePurchase.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="loan" src = "images/liabilities/loan.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="overdraft" src = "images/liabilities/overdraft.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="payeTax" src = "images/liabilities/payeTax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="tax" src = "images/liabilities/tax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
</section>
```

but I'm not sure how to reference the HTML images. I tried doing it in a similar way to the way you would reference the images in JavaScript directly from their sources:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {
        asset1: document.getElementById("building");
        asset2: document.getElementById("chair");
    }
}
```

but when I loaded the page in the browser, my canvas was no longer displayed.
So far I have managed to get the canvas displaying, with one image that can be dragged and dropped around the canvas using this code:

```
var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'images/assets/building.png';
```

but obviously the problem with this is that if I was to provide the administrator with a form where they could change the src of the image that's drawn from 'building.png' to some other image file, I wouldn't be able to replace the line that's loading the 'building' image in the hidden section of my HTML with a line to now load the new image instead.

Does anyone know how I can reference the HTML images from within the JavaScript?

**Edit 10/12/2012 @ 21:00**

I tried changing the code to:

```
var sources = {
        asset1: document.getElementById("building"),
        asset2: document.getElementById("chair")
    }
```

but my canvas still wasn't displayed when viewing the page in the browser. I also tried that with a comma after the second line, but the canvas wasn't displayed.

**Edit 10/12/2012 @ 22:55**

I now have this function:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {
        asset1: document.getElementById("building").src,
        asset2: document.getElementById("chair").src,
    };
    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
};
```

and try to draw the image on the canvas with this code:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
  imageObj.src = sources.asset1;
```

but for some reason, this has again stopped the canvas from displaying in the browser... The only thing I've changed since it was displaying in the browser is the line: `imageObj.src = sources.asset1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
var sources = {
    asset1: document.getElementById("building");
    asset2: document.getElementById("chair");
}
```

produces a syntax error. Your property declarations should end with **commas**, not semicolons (as you did correctly in your first object declaration).

The reason your canvas disappeared when you tried that code is because the script interpreter halted on the syntax error.

**EDIT:**

If you want to recreate your first object (the one with image URL strings) using image elements from the DOM, get the `src` property of each element:

```
var sources = {
    asset1: document.getElementById("building").src,
    asset2: document.getElementById("chair").src
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer- I tried altering the code as you suggested, but still had the problem with the canvas not being displayed in the browser. I've added what I tried to my original question.

Comment: @someone2088 Wait, do you want to get the *source* of each image or each entire image object? If you only want the source URL, use the `src` property, e.g., `document.getElementById("chair").src`. Right now your code is storing an object into `source.asset1`, not a string.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get the source of each image, so that all of the images that I had 'preloaded' in the HTML are displayed on the canvas using the JavaScript. Thanks, I think I understand that.

Comment: Although after changing it to `asset1: document.getElementById("building").src,` etc, when I view the page in the browser, although the canvas is now displayed in the browser, the only image displayed on it is the building.png image which as far as I can tell, is coming from the line `imageObj.src = 'images/assets/building.png';`. How would I now change the `imageObj.src = ` line to reference each of the sources I've put in the `var sources = {...}; ` array? Would it be: `imageObj.src = sources.asset1;` ?

Comment: Or maybe `imageObj.src = sources[0];` since 'sources' is an array?

Comment: `sources` is not an array; it is a simple object. You can access its members like `sources.asset1` or with `sources["asset1"]` (which could allow you to do `sources["asset"+i]` to loop over all the members).

Comment: I tried changing it to `imageObj.src = sources["asset1"];` but for some reason, when viewing it in the page, the canvas has stopped displaying again... any ideas?

Comment: Changing it to `imageObj.src = sources.asset1;` also stops the canvas from being displayed in the browser